# How did Frank figure out Jim was a spy?

Tags: manhattan

In the season 2 finale of Manhattan Paul tells Frank to call Jim's mother to prove to Frank that Jim is a spy.

How does did this prove that Jim is the spy? I'm guessing I missed or forgot about some earlier part of the season.

Answer (score 1):

Paul never has any definitive proof that Jim is the spy, but infers that he is from two "coincidences" that were observed in Season 2, Episode 9 ("Brooklyn").

After Victor (Nora's father, the other agent colluding with the Russians, credited as "The Handler") is captured, during the interrogation with Bucher and Paul, he appeals to the fact that that Paul is also a father, which, until that point was only known by a handful of Paul's peers and Hogarth. Victor backpedals and tries to speak in generalities, but it's clear that he was driving at the fact that Paul had a son.

During the same interrogation, Bucher produces a piece of burned paper that has "Brooklyn" written in a portion that was not fully burned off.  Victor claimed this referred to Sid Liao, the member of Jim's group that had been falsely accused of being a spy. Sid had a Brooklyn Dodgers hat, which was later taken as a memento by Jim when Sid was killed.  When Paul is watching Fritz's footage of his wedding after Jeannie's death, the camera zooms in on Jim (who had been the best man at the wedding, and was wearing the hat at that time), and Paul realizes that the "Brooklyn" in the letter is likely referring to Jim and not Sid.

Much of this is information is confirmed [here](https://www.atomicheritage.org/article/%E2%80%9Cmanhattan%E2%80%9D-season-2-episode-9-%E2%80%9Cwe-see-no-acceptable-alternative%E2%80%9D).